# How to write evaluate function for a pretrained model and specify a dataloader?

Tags: machine-learning, allennlp

I am new to the AllenNLP library. I am using the Pretrained Bidaf-elmo model for a reading comprehension task. My code looks like -

```html
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models.rc
from allennlp_models import pretrained
from allennlp.training.util import evaluate
import allennlp.data.data_loaders.simple_data_loader

archive_file_path = "https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bidaf-model-2020.03.19.tar.gz"
input_path = "C:\\Users\\SHRIPRIYA\\sample_dataset.json"

data_load = simple_data_loader(input_path)
evaluate(model=archive_file_path, data_loader = data_load, output_file=output, predictions_output_file=pred_output_file, cuda_device=0)
```

The line `simple_data_loader()` throws an error - `name 'simple_data_loader' is not defined`. I know this is a syntax error but I could not find any examples to load a JSON file using a Data Loader function from AllenNLP and evaluate it using a pre-trained model.

About my data:

1. total sample passages = 10,000
2. total questions = 1000

Each sample passage needs to be subjected to all the 1000 questions. My sample JSON input looks like -

```
{
  "passage": "Venus is named after the Roman goddess of love and beauty. Venus is the second planet from the sun. Is the brightest object in the sky besides our Sun and the Moon. Venus has no moons. It is also known as the morning star because at sunrise it appears in the east. It is also known as the evening star as it appears at sunset when it is in the west. It cannot be seen in the middle of the night. Venus and Earth are close together in space and similar in size, which is the reason Venus is called Earth's sister planet. Venus has more volcanoes than any other planet. It is the hottest planet in the solar system, even hotter than Mercury, which is closer to the Sun. The temperature on the surface of Venus is about 460° Celsius. The atmosphere on Venus is composed of carbon dioxide. The surface is heated by radiation from the sun, but the heat cannot escape through the clouds and layer of carbon dioxide. (This is a “greenhouse effect”).",
  "questions": [
    "How many moons does Venus have?",
    "Venus was named after which Roman goddess?",    
    "At what position does Venus lie from Sun?",
    "What is the temperature of Venus surface?",
    "Why is Venus called Earth’s sister planet?",
    "What is the atmosphere of Venus composed of?"
  ]}
```

If there's any faster alternative to evaluate multiple questions against multiple passages, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you haven't imported `SimpleDataLoader` properly. The following should work:
`from allennlp.data.data_loaders import SimpleDataLoader`

You can find examples of training and evaluating a model here: https://guide.allennlp.org/training-and-prediction#3

Comment: The data is loaded successfully but the evaluate function throws the following error `'ReadingComprehensionPredictor' object has no attribute 'eval'`.  I am loading the pre-trained model using the command: `predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bidaf-model-2020.03.19.tar.gz")`. Any alternatives?